# Rellenar espacio de un control dentro de un panel en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Sigo con mi proyecto en Winforms C# y tengo muchos problemas ya que solo conozco WPF y Silverlight que es muy parecido.

En WPF si pongo, en el `XAML`:

```
 HorizontalAlignment="Strench"     
 VerticalAlignment="Strench"
```

Sin poner el alto y ancho el control se ajusta al tamaño del padre, ¿cómo se realiza en WinForms?

En este momento tengo un panel genérico, con el tamaño que quiero.

Ya que no existe `XAML` en proyectos [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Utiliza la propidedad `Dock` del Control Hijo, tienes que ajustarla a `Fill`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es el cuadro central

Esto ajustará el tamaño al elemento padre, ignorando la altura y tamaño del control, y si la ventana cambia de tamaño también cambiará este control, simpre y cuando su padre superior pueda ajustarse.

Comment: ok ya lo puede realizar

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer así:

```
const int MARGEN = 2;
. . .
miControl.Location.X = MARGEN;
miControl.Location.Y = MARGEN;
miControl.Size.Width = miPanel.Width - (MARGEN*2);
miControl.Size.Height = miPanel.Height - (MARGEN*2);
```